# Tic-Tac-Toe Javascript, can't determine a loop or function to check winner

Tags: javascript, arrays, comparison

Tic-Tac-Toe is the code I'm working on, but my question is just a general one. How can I go about checking one array of integers against one large array containing several sub-arrays of integers. I only want to find the numbers from 'sel' that appear in one of the arrays in 'combos'. So far I have tried to filter, find, indexOf, and map, but I never get the code to 'find' just the relevant numbers from 'sel'... I know I can I can use the following code to get the job done:

```
if(document.getElementById('1') && 
   document.getElementById('2') && 
   document.getElementById('3') == 'X'){
 alert('You Win')}
```

but it seems redundant, and I would like to know the efficient way to solve this problem. Please don't suggest any Jquery, I am using Vanilla JS without any libraries. And please make sure you check both my question and the other author before marking mine as a duplicate, because I have researched this question for hours, and could not find one similar. If there is one, please point me in the right direction. I don't think the rest of my code is relevant, but if you would like to see it anyway, I will attach.

```js
function play(player) {

  var arr = [];
  var player;
  var computer;
  var turn1 = ['X', 'O'];
  var check = [];
  var p = document.getElementById('page');
 
  player = player.value;
  p.innerHTML = 'You Will Play As' + '<br>' + player;
  computer = turn1.filter(v => v !== player);
  mouseD();

  function mouseD() {
    var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    arr = Array.from(div);
    for (var i in arr) {
      arr[i].onmousedown = function() {
        var values = this.getAttribute('id');
        if (check.indexOf(values) > -1) {
          alert('select a different box');
        } else {
          this.innerHTML = player;
          check.push(values);
        }
      }
      arr[i].onmouseup = function() {
        var temp = [];
        var arr1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
        for (var j in arr1) {
          if (check.indexOf(arr1[j]) === -1) temp.push(arr1[j]);
        }
        for (j in check) {
          if (arr1.indexOf(check[j]) === -1) temp.push(check[j]);
        }
        var some = Math.floor(Math.random() * temp.length);
        var all = temp[some];
        var vals = document.getElementById(all);
        vals.innerHTML = computer;
        check.push(all);
        winner();
      }
      function winner() {
        var combos = [
          ['1', '2', '3'],
          ['4', '5', '6'],
          ['7', '8', '9'],
          ['1', '4', '7'],
          ['2', '6', '8'],
          ['3', '6', '9'],
          ['3', '5', '7'],
          ['1', '5', '9']
        ];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  border: 5px slategray solid;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}

section {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p id='page'>
    <button class='button' id='X' value='X' onclick='play(this)'>X
</button>
    <button class='button' id='O' value='O' onclick='play(this)'>O
    </button>
  </p>
  <br>
  <section>
    <div id='1' class='box' value='1'>
    </div>
    <div id='2' class='box' value='2'>
    </div>
    <div id='3' class='box' value='3'>
    </div>
    </br>
    <div id='4' class='box' value='4'>
    </div>
    <div id='5' class='box' value='5'>
    </div>
    <div id='6' class='box' value='6'>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id='7' class='box' value='7'>
    </div>
    <div id='8' class='box' value='8'>
    </div>
    <div id='9' class='box' value='9'>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

```
var combos = 
       [['1', '2', '3'],
        ['4', '5', '6'],
        ['7', '8', '9'],
        ['1', '4', '7'],
        ['2', '6', '8'],
        ['3', '6', '9'],
        ['3', '5', '7'],
        ['1', '5', '9']];

var sel = ['1','2','6','8'];
```

Comment: Is [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/u5fyjrbe/) what you're looking for ?

Comment: I don't really get it... I think it's close though :) I just used 'sel' as an example of the boxes that could be selected. I just want to test 'sel' against 'combos' and get a true/false answer if 'sel' is part of 'combo'... so the example I put should say 'true' because '2', '6, '8 are all part of combos[4].  But if the 'sel' were ['1','2','4'] I would get false, because they are not part of one of the sub arrays of combos. Does that help, or did I just make it more confusing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `some()`, `every()` and `indexOf()` and it will return `true/false` as result.

```js
var combos = 
       [['1', '2', '3'],
        ['4', '5', '6'],
        ['7', '8', '9'],
        ['1', '4', '7'],
        ['2', '6', '8'],
        ['3', '6', '9'],
        ['3', '5', '7'],
        ['1', '5', '9']];

var sel = ['1','2','6','8'];

var result = combos.some(function(ar) {
  return ar.every(function(e) {
    return sel.indexOf(e) != -1
  })
})

console.log(result)
```

Here is shorter version with `ES6/ES7` using arrow functions and `Array#includes`

```
var result = combos.some((ar) => ar.every((e) => sel.includes(e)))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!!! Thank you so much! I have tried like every variation of this... except this... (well probably not even close to this :)

Comment: Is there a possible `for` loop algorithm that will return the array `combos` ?

Answer (score 1):

well, you can test for each X inserted if it forms a straight line:

```
// in your game loop
int index = input(player);
int indexTest = index;
if (testHorizontal(indexTest, player)) gameOver();
if (testVertical(indexTest, player)) gameOver();
if (testDiagonal(indexTest, player)) gameOver();
```

and then we define those methods

```
// defined methods

public boolean testHorizontal(indexTest, player){
     int x = getX(indexTest); // you'll need only the horizontal index
     for (int i =0; i < boardLength; i++){
          if (!isPlayer(player, board[x][i])){ // whenever we find a non "X" check case, we return false and continue our loop
               return false;
          }
     }
     return true; // means all the line is checked by the player (X for example)
}

public boolean testVertical(indexTest, player){ // same as horizontal
     int y = getY(indexTest);
     for (int i =0; i < boardLength; i++){
          if (!isPlayer(player, board[i][y])){
               return false;
          }
     }
     return true;
}


public boolean testDiagonal(indexTest, player){
     int x = getX(indexTest);
     int y = getY(indexTest);

     if (x == y){   // then from up to down, ie from 0.0 to 3.3 or 5.5,...
          for (int i =0; i<boardLength; i++){
               if (!isPlayer(player, board[i][i])) return false;
          }
          return true;
     }
     if ((x == (boardLength - y)) || (y == (boardLength -x)){ // then from down to up ie from 0.3 to 3.0, ...
          for (int i=0; i<boardLength; i++){
              if (!isPlayer(player, board[i][boardLength - i])) 
                   return false;
          }
          return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```

while boardLength is a global static var representing the size of the board (can be 3x3 or more)

should work, or something like it. and can be improved.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had thought about checking for a straight line, but didn't know how to implement. I will keep your answer in my notes for other games I create, I can see it coming in handy in a variety of web games. :)